# Setting Linear mixed model for within-subject crossed factors

Tags: mixed-model, spss, repeated-measures, accuracy

I have problems in undertanding how to correctly run a mixed linear model.

I have done an experiment to compare three groups (1 between-subject factor); for each subject, 2 sensory stimuli are given (factor1), each stimulus is given in 3 conditions (factor2), for each condition 3 different spatial positions are used on a screen (factor3). Subjects have to answer which condition they are presented.

Thus, I have 3 way crossed factorial design (2x3x3).

Each subject gives N responses for each combination of factors. Then average accuracy rates (ACC) and average reactions times are registered for each combination (RT).

Since I have missing data in some conditions I want to use linear mixed model.

For the moment I am interested in understanding how accuracy rates change according to my main effects as well as interations between my within-subject factors and between-subject factor by accounting for age, gender and RT.

I am new to mixed models.

I have inserted (in spss) my main effects as well as interactions between grouping factor and my within subject factors treating them as fixed factors. I treated covariates as fixed factors as well.

As far as I have understood I can account for differences among subjects by including a random intercept to the model.

I would like to know whether my model is correct in this way or if I have to further model covariance structure of residuals (using for instance a /repeated statement in SPSS format).

Any comment will be appreciated!

Best,

Alessandro

Comment: If you are just asking for SPSS code, that would be off topic here (but presumably on topic on [SO]). But you may have a statistical question (in which case, CV is appropriate). Please edit to clarify what you need. If you want your question migrated to [SO], just flag it for the moderators. You can also ask a statistical question here, and a *related* coding question there.

Comment: Hi gung, my basic question is on the correctness of the model I built. Thank for your suggestion, I modified my question accordingly. I will post a separate question on spss syntax on Stack Overflow. Best